# Delete entity while using two instances of EntityManger

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-delete, hibernate-entitymanager

I am trying to delete entity but I get this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance`

I understand that my problem is that I am using two different EntityManger instances. I looked out for a solution but all the solutions that I found was something like this:

```
entityManger.remove(entityManger.merge(entity));
```

There is another way to solve this issue instead of using merge and remove function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception said that your entity is not managed by persistent context. You can not delete not managed entity. You can use

```
Entity entity = entityManager.getReference(Entity.class, id);
entityManager.remove(entity);
```

It is better, becouse you get lazy instance.
Sorry for my english)

Comment: This is don't throw me exception but it dind't delete my entity, probably because I am doing getReference with one EntityManager and remove with other EntityManager.

Comment: I dont know how it is possible) But use EntityManager which сontrols the entity you want to delete. And why do you have two  EntityManager? You two DataBase?

Comment: In one class I find the entity that I want to delete (First EntityManger). That class call to other class that there I actaully remove the object (Second EntityManger).

Comment: Ok. As for me, the logic of the program is incorrect. You do not need to create multiple Entity Manager. Create one in a separate class and use it everywhere. And be sure to use transaction transactions.

Comment: Yeah I changed a little bit of the architecture and used your solution. Thanks!